# Google Auth don't show popup if logged in

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

In scenario 1 the user is not logged into our app and is not logged into google in their browser. This shows them a pop up and tells them to log in to google and then tells them to authorize our app.

However, in my scenario, the user is already logged in and already has authorized my app. I log them in automatically but the problem is that the popup keeps appearing each time.

Is there a way to call the signin of google api without having the popup show?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store the "is logged in" somewhere, cookie or database or session and if it is set don't call the google api

Comment: the case is where they come to the site for the first time after a cookie has expired. They still need to log in but not have the pop up. Can I be more clear somehow about this? Any suggestions would be great :)

Comment: Edit: I have no idea of how to call the API without showing the popup.

Comment: What library are you using to authenticate to Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you marked this question as Javascript, I guess you must be using the oauth 2.0 through Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript.
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/

In this page, https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication.
Checkout the Auth example section, when you make the call **gapi.auth.authorize(params, callback)**, set the param **immediate** to be **true**, so that the token is refreshed behind the scenes and no UI is shown to the user.

Checkout this page to see more details about the method gapi.auth.authorize(params, callback).
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthauthorize